# How to set max value in @Size annotation from properties file?

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

I'm using Hibernate Validator Version 5.3.0.

Following is the class I want to validate.

```
public class DocumentRequest {

    @NotEmpty(message="{invalid.docId}")
    private String docId;

    @NotEmpty(message="{invalid.title}")
    @Size(max=200, message="{invalid.title}")
    private String title;
}
```

The problem here is the **max** value of `@Size` is a *"magic"* number(Quoting `Sonar`). 
How can I set it from properties file?

I tried to add it as follows:

```
public class DocumentRequest {

    @NotEmpty(message="{invalid.docId}")
    private String docId;

    @NotEmpty(message="{invalid.title}")
    @Size(max="{max.default.value}", message="{invalid.title}")
    private String title;
}
```

I added `max.default.value` in validation.properties file, but the max can be `int` and I'm passing `String` to it. So as a result:

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int`

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just because Sonar whines about something doesn't mean your code is bad.

Sonar will already be happy if you put this "magic" value into a `private static final` at the top of your class.  No need to make it a property (I doubt your system would react well if someone decided to change this later on).

Comment: Agreed, that Sonar flags constants in annotations as an issue seems just misguided. That said, we have an API for dynamic constraint declation in Hibernate Validator which you *could* use, but really it's not what should be done in this case.